# ruby change content of a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

I'm doing data processing, one task is to get stats of people distribution. Say for the people of name "john doe", there fall in different states, ca, ar, and ny, and of different age groups, twenties, thirties, etc. {1,2} or {3} is the people's id.

```
"john doe" => "ca:tw#2{1,2}:th#1{3};ar:tw#1{4}:fi#1{5};ny:tw#1{6};"
```

Now if I want to get the id of john doe in ca with age tw, how should I get them? Maybe using Regex? And if I want to add a new id to it, say 100, now it becomes

```
"john doe" => "ca:tw#3{1,2,100}:th#1{3};ar:tw#1{4}:fi#1{5};ny:tw#1{6};"
```

how should I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a string to store this data instead of a more suited data structure?

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, it might help to import the data and convert it to an XML document. A gem like Nokogiri can then work with it very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with string manipulation, you can use regex and gsub.

Here is one way to do it. It could use some clean up (eg error handling, re-factoring, etc.), but I think it would get you started.

```
def count(details, location, age_group)
    location_details = /#{location}(.+?);/.match(details)[1]
    age_count = /#{age_group}#(\d+)\{/.match(details)[1]
    return age_count.to_i
end

def ids(details, location, age_group)
    location_details = /#{location}(.+?);/.match(details)[1]
    age_ids = /#{age_group}#\d+\{(.+?)\}/.match(details)[1]
    return age_ids
end

def add(details, location, age_group, new_id)
    location_details = /#{location}(.+?);/.match(details)[1]
    new_count = count(details, location, age_group) + 1
    new_ids = ids(details, location, age_group) + ',' + new_id
    location_details.gsub!(/#{age_group}#\d+\{(.+?)\}/, "#{age_group}##{new_count}{#{new_ids}}")
    details.gsub!(/#{location}(.+?);/, "#{location}#{location_details};")
end
```

You can see it produces the results you wanted (at least functionally, not sure about performance):

```
names = {"john doe" => "ca:tw#2{1,2}:th#1{3};ar:tw#1{4}:fi#1{5};ny:tw#1{6};"}
puts count(names["john doe"], 'ca', 'tw')
#=> 2
puts ids(names["john doe"], 'ca', 'tw')
#=> 1,2
names["john doe"] = add(names["john doe"], 'ca', 'tw', '100')
puts names["john doe"]
#=> ca:tw#3{1,2,100}:th#1{3};ar:tw#1{4}:fi#1{5};ny:tw#1{6};
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to use a string for this inside the program.  You may read the data from a string as it is stored, or write it back out that way, but you should store it in a manner that's easy to manipulate.  For instance:

```
data = {
  "john doe" => {
    "ca" => {
      "tw" => [1,2],
      "th" => [3]
    },
    "ar" => {
       "tw" => [4],
       "fi" => [5]
    },
    "ny" => { 
       "tw" => [6]
    }
  }
}
```

Given that, the ids of the California John Doe's in their 20's are `data['john doe']['ca']['tw']`.  The number of such John Doe's is `data['john doe']['ca']['tw'].length`; the first id is `data['john doe']['ca']['tw'][0]`, and the second is `data['john doe']['ca']['tw'][1]`.   You could add id 100 to it with `data['john doe']['ca']['tw'] << 100`; 100 would then be the value of `data['john doe']['ca']['tw'][2]`.

If I were writing this, though, I would probably use actual numbers for the age-range keys (20, 30, 50) instead of those obscure letter prefixes.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that make sense but hash seems to be slow when processing a large dataset. I tried your method and it takes too long time, so I'm thinking about string representation.

Comment: Not sure that string-manipulation is going to be much faster than Hash access.  What Ruby implementation are you using?

Comment: something like this  name_hash = {:"jose garcia"=> {:ca => {:tw => {:count=>2, :id=>"1,2,"}, :th => {:count=>3, :id=>"3,4,5,"}}, :ak =>{:tw=> {:count=>1, :id =>"22,"}}}, 
:"john doe" => {:ar =>{:tw => {:count=>1, :id=>"95,"}}}}

Comment: I mean, what engine/version - MRI?  JRuby?  1.8, 1.9? etc.  Makes a big difference as far as performance goes.